# How to update Android Studio in Ubuntu?

Tags: android-studio

I am trying to update from version **2.0.0** to version **2.1.2** in Ubuntu 64bit/14.04LTS but when I click "**update and restart**" it says "Downloading patches" and it closes.

It does not start again and if I try to open it, the version is still 2.0.0.

Is there any tutorial to manually update android studio? (keep all settings and etc).

Comment: please mention your ubuntu version and the mode of update so it would be better to say suggestions related to it

Comment: Try to ***Reboot*** you computer then try again if not working may be you will need to reinstall **Android Studio**.

Answer (score 9):

The first time I installed *Android Studio*, I followed the instructions given at: https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/install-android-studio-ubuntu-16-04

Basically

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:maarten-fonville/android-studio

sudo apt update

sudo apt install android-studio
```

With this you have a clean installation of android studio

Then, when I need to update it, I just rerun

```
sudo apt install android-studio
```

If you didn't use this method, it's worth a try.  It is cleaner in the long run.

Comment: The important commands were added, hope it helps

Answer (score 4):

I experienced the same issue when trying to update from 2.1.0 to 2.1.1 and the update problem still persisted after the Android Studio 2.1.2 release.

In the end the only option was a clean install of Android Studio.

To keep your existing Android Studio settings download and [install the latest version](https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html) into a different folder. When the new installation of Android Studio is run for the first time it will prompt you to import your settings from the older Android Studio version you have installed.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I found that after the patch is downloaded Android Studio tries to update itself but as it is run without **sudo** rights it fallbacks to simply run the old version of Android Studio without updating it.

In order to update my old version of Android studio I went to the folder where Android studio was installed, in my case *~/apps/android-studio/bin/*, and run with **sudo** Android Studio, in my case **sudo ./studio.sh**

It will then ask you for your Android Studio configuration file. Be careful about the location where the installation process will install a new Android SDK version,  because in my case it wanted to install it in the wrong directory,  I had to select *custom installation* in order to select the folder where I had my previous Android SDK.

Answer (score 2):

The best way in my opinion is to use JetBrains Toolbox.

https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox-app/

This small app allows you to update your JetBrains tools, including the official Android Studio. It detects Android Studio even if you did a manual setup.

Comment: Actually the recommended way by Android Studio as well

Answer (score 1):

To update Android Studio, the Android Studio was saying the it needed the writing access for the folder "android-studio where it's installed, by default is in `$HOME/android-studio/.

How you find the permissions?

1. Look the tutorial in https://ostoday.org/linux/how-to-give-write-permission-to-a-folder-in-linux.html that has this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zR_Ibd-ZOzo
2. Open your terminal and write `cd <the directory where android-studio is located>` (in may case, `cd $HOME`) to go to the directory.
3. Write on the terminal `ls -l` to see the list of permissions.
   [image]
   You can see the directory or `d` has enabled read `r`, write `w` and execute `x` for the user `root`, group of user. But others has only `r and` x`, not` w`. This means Android Studio program hasn't writing access for the folder` android-studio`.
4. To enable writing access, you put on the terminal `sudo chmod o+w android-studio`.

Now you can update Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I always download my Android Studio mannually from:

http://tools.android.com/download/studio/builds/android-studio-2-2-stable

and Android SDK from: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html

During instalation I select exisitng unpacked SDK instead of downloading during installation - it causes problems with not well downloaded packages

Try next time this way.

Hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have permissions issues.

This is quick, not very good fix. `sudo chmod -R 777 [android studio folder]`. This will give all permissions to everyone for that folder, this might not be a big deal for your home private machine, but for work/public one obviously you don't want that.

Good fix would be setting the proper permissions to the folder and subfolders where your Android studio is installed.

Comment: Can you show him how to set these permission.

Answer (score 0):

Execute the 'studio.sh' file by specifying the complete path.
I ran it from my $HOME directory using command: /opt/android-studio/bin/studio.sh'

[Note: android-studio directory was given complete permissions previously. So, you may try 'sudo' in case appropriate permissions are not allotted]

Answer (score 0):

Updating from android-studio 2022.3.1(giraffe) to android-studio 2023.1.1(hedgehog). The update dialog box opened my chrome and started downloading the latest android studio IDE.
I extracted the tar.gz archive and replaced the android-studio(hedgehog) folder with existing android-studio(giraffe) folder.
The location of my android-studio(giraffe) installed was `/usr/local/lib/android-studio`
After performing these steps I simply clicked the android studio Icon on my desktop and Boom!! the IDE got updated without all my existing settings and plugins disabled (which ofcourse I did)